# Getting results from table sequentially in foreach?

Tags: powershell

I have the following powershell script that is supposed to run a process command on the cubes after ordering their sequence in the table

```
param($App_input, $Script) #%2 and %3 arguments from cmd line input;

Function Query($Query) {
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$Server;Initial Catalog=$Database;Integrated Security=SSPI" 
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $Query 
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet 
$a=$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close() 
$DataSet.Tables[0] }

#$cube = Query "SELECT DISTINCT cube_name, sequence FROM [dbo].[$cubeTable] WHERE [application] = '$App_input' ORDER BY [sequence]" | Select -ExpandProperty cube_name;

$Table = Query "SELECT * from [dbo].[$cubeTable]"

                  # -ExpandProperty trims the column name, so it only outputs the value, not with header!

$App = Query "SELECT DISTINCT[application] FROM [dbo].[$cubeTable] WHERE [application] = '$App_input'" | Select -ExpandProperty application;

    $i=0
    $CUBE = @()

    foreach($row in $Table | where { $_.application -match $App })
    {   
        $i++
        $CUBE += $row.Item("cube_name")
        write-host " > CUBE $($i):" $CUBE[$CUBE -1]
        cmd /c "runPowerShell.bat $Script $CUBE"    #where $Script is Process.ps1 script that processes on each CUBE selected from table in order
    }
```

This is the hypothetical table:

[image: Table]

for example: if i were to pass in the app parameter and the script parameter as such:

someBatchFile.bat SSP Process.ps1

the script first should check that the loop is only returning results where [application] column = SSP, so avoiding the 3rd row in this case. however, the where clause i have `$_.application -match $App` for some reason is not having any effect, and the powershell returns all rows regardless...

after that check is done, the script should order the rows (from 2, 2, 1 to 1, 2, 2) returning CUBE2, CUBE1 (just one time since its distinct) which is passed in each iteration to `$CUBE` in the cmd line.

essentially, in this examples, the iterations should look like this:

> cmd /c "runPowerShell.bat $Process.ps1 CUBE2"
>
> cmd /c "runPowerShell.bat $Process.ps1 CUBE1"

I know order by would be helpful in this case, but i dont know how can i use that in the case of foreach and `$row.Item`

Comment: I would suggest you to debug the script in an Editor, say VSCode or PowerShell ISE.

Comment: @PRASOON KARUNAN V I am guessing because you're suspecting the match condition is glitching in powershell CMD but the ISE is more accurate right? Anyhow, the main part I would like help with is the looping by sequence instead

Comment: What you need to check here is the value in `$App` , where condition is depended on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Query` functions returns `DataTable` type object which means `$Table` variable is `DataTable` too.

For `DataTable` type variable you want to use `Select()` method to get filtered results. Like so:

```
$Table.Select("application = '$App'")
```

Also. Check out your whole code, this things looks really wierd for me.

```
param($App_input, $Script)

$App = Query "SELECT DISTINCT[application] FROM [dbo].[$cubeTable] WHERE [application] = '$App_input'" | Select -ExpandProperty application;
```

You are passing **$application** to the script to next pass it for query that should return **application** value from database table while that query's filter condition is equals to **application** value.

You could just use **application** value already.

Comment: i changed it to foreach($row in $Table | where { $Table.Select("application = '$App_input'") }) but its giving me error: Method invocation failed because [System.Data.DataRow] does not contain a method named 'Select'.

Comment: even with ""$_.application -match $App_input"?" instead of $App it still returns all 4 rows when it should only be 3 .....

Comment: ok so after none of these suggestions were working right, i tried this "$Table = Query "SELECT * from [dbo].[$cubeTable] WHERE [application] = '$App_input'"" and it select just 3 now as it should! now i need help with the sequence

Comment: nvm i figure it out. i could just add ORDER BY [sequence] to the $Table query

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

I could have just done the checks in `$Table`

```
$Table = Query "SELECT * from [dbo].[$cubeTable] WHERE [application] = '$App_input' AND [active] = 'TRUE' ORDER BY [sequence]"

    $i=0
    $CUBE = @()

    foreach($row in $Table)
    {   
        $i++
        $CUBE += $row.Item("cube_name")
        write-host " > CUBE $($i): $($CUBE[-1])`n"
        cmd /c "runPowerShell.bat $Script $($CUBE[-1])" #where $Script is Process.ps1 script that processes on each CUBE selected from table in order
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$App = Query "SELECT DISTINCT cube_name FROM [dbo].[$cubeTable] WHERE [application] = '$App_input'"
$i=0

$App | %{

    $i++
    $CUBE=$_.Item("cube_name")
    " > CUBE $i : $CUBE"
    cmd /c "runPowerShell.bat $Script $CUBE"
}
```

Comment: Is that...another method of for looping?  ”%{”. Can you please explain lol, it looks really interesting. Not gonna lie I laughed at how simple it looks as soon as I saw just  %{ with the for each gone 

Comment: % is an alias for "foreach" :)   My proposition are a correct answer for you?

Comment: Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method named 'Item'